# Spring Kafka Without spring boot consumer not consuming messages

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

Consumer using Spring’s JavaConfig class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    public static final String TOPIC = "test-1";
    private String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

Kafka topic listener using @KafkaListener annotation as follows:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListener.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = KafkaConfig.TOPIC)
    public void handle(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) {
        LOGGER.info("Message: "+cr.key()+"="+cr.value());
    }
}
```

And my pom includes dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now When i package to war and deploy to tomcat, It doesn't show any errors not even in debug mode just deploys war and nothing.

Please help me understand if i am missing some configuration that triggers the kafkalistner.

Thanks Gary I addedd the context.xml and web.xml but i get bean errors mentioned in below comments

Web.XML

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Context.XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller.*" />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that spring by default uses XmlWebApplicationContext, so i had to explicitly tell Spring to create application context for web applications by using java clases as input for bean definitions instead of xml files.

Below is the change done to context.xml. This Worked for me.

`

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.common.controller.KafkaConfig</param-value>
</context-param>`
```

Answer (score 0):

When deploying in a war, you need to bootstrap the application context via the web.xml. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-integration-common

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In the context.xml add `<context:component-scan/>`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-autodetection

Comment: I see you are new here - don't put stuff like that in comments; it's too hard to read; delete the comments and edit the question instead. Then add a comment that you have done so, so I'll get a notification.

Comment: Thanks Gary have done as requested but i see errors like below at startup.  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXPa
rseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 71; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Comment: After updating the versions to 3.0 in context.xml bean errors issue resolved But still don't see kafkalistener being invoked no logs in tomcat.

Comment: Remove the version from the xsd and make sure you are using the right spring version (2.2.6 uses spring-framework 5.1.7). Even better, use the latest 2.2.4 and 5.2.5 respectively. Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework to see the bean creation process.